# docker swarm, tasks of service are not deployed to a new created swarm worker node

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

There are already two swarm nodes: `myvm1` and `myvm2`.

Here is my service and tasks, they are already deployed to `myvm1` and `myvm2` node.

```
☁  docker-research [master] ⚡  docker service ls
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                        PORTS
pwjxzu80q1vx        getstartedlab_web   replicated          5/5                 novaline/get-started:part2   *:4000->80/tcp
☁  docker-research [master] ⚡  docker service ps getstartedlab_web
ID                  NAME                  IMAGE                        NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE            ERROR               PORTS
32c88logpvar        getstartedlab_web.1   novaline/get-started:part2   myvm2               Running             Running 3 hours ago
3lpx3gotggi8        getstartedlab_web.2   novaline/get-started:part2   myvm1               Running             Running 3 hours ago
meuwm1dhxeba        getstartedlab_web.3   novaline/get-started:part2   myvm2               Running             Running 3 hours ago
jrxs9xbjxz56        getstartedlab_web.4   novaline/get-started:part2   myvm1               Running             Running 33 minutes ago
oocrasndz98s        getstartedlab_web.5   novaline/get-started:part2   myvm1               Running             Running 33 minutes ago
```

Now, I want to add a new swarm worker node - `myvm3`

Here is my steps:

create new VM - `myvm3`:

`docker-machine create -d virtualbox myvm3`

add `myvm3` to swarm as a worker node:

```
☁  docker-research [master] ⚡  docker-machine ssh myvm3 'docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-002x9ve85tv0jpodgd0y1244itb2knyr3b6j4qn6qiepl7yjx7-4p08k808lz9eqtqu1szdki3md 192.168.99.100:2377'
This node joined a swarm as a worker.
```

check swarm nodes:

```
☁  docker-research [master] ⚡  docker node ls
ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
qciplvmrh6j758hs8mi8jyqdz *   myvm1               Ready               Active              Leader              18.05.0-ce
5xxrbayq0n0068awdctneyifg     myvm2               Ready               Active                                  18.05.0-ce
gfuc93zs1k45evlhlxqfd2qo9     myvm3               Ready               Active                                  18.05.0-ce
```

deploy again:

```
☁  docker-research [master] ⚡  docker stack deploy getstartedlab -c ./get-started-v2/docker-compose.yml
Updating service getstartedlab_web (id: pwjxzu80q1vxejc3d3hzoc89l)
```

Now, I think the tasks of service will be deployed to three nodes - `myvm1`, `myvm2` and `myvm3`. But when I check the tasks status again, the tasks are still deployed in `myvm1` and `myvm2` nodes.

```
☁  docker-research [master] ⚡  docker service ps getstartedlab_web
ID                  NAME                  IMAGE                        NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE               ERROR               PORTS
32c88logpvar        getstartedlab_web.1   novaline/get-started:part2   myvm2               Running             Running 4 hours ago
3lpx3gotggi8        getstartedlab_web.2   novaline/get-started:part2   myvm1               Running             Running 4 hours ago
meuwm1dhxeba        getstartedlab_web.3   novaline/get-started:part2   myvm2               Running             Running 4 hours ago
jrxs9xbjxz56        getstartedlab_web.4   novaline/get-started:part2   myvm1               Running             Running about an hour ago
oocrasndz98s        getstartedlab_web.5   novaline/get-started:part2   myvm1               Running             Running about an hour ago
```

What can I do if I want the service be deployed in all nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You have to deploy the services as Global mode, as soon as new node available ,scheduler places a task on the all the available nodes. Add mode : Global to the deploy tag in your compose file as shown below(highlighted with bold). It should it create a tasks on all the available nodes. Hope this helps.

services:
 flask-app:
    image: 127.0.0.1:5003/flask-app:latest
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - flask-mysql
    command: python3 /opt/app.py
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"
    networks:
      - overlay
    **deploy:
      mode: global**